# Error when using image tag in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I a trying to build a app using react.

When I try to use image tag to load image from server I face the following error.

```
index_bundle.js:897 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__reactInternalInstance$1sguwxb6jxb' of null
at Object.getClosestInstanceFromNode (index_bundle.js:897)
at findParent (index_bundle.js:29731)
at handleTopLevelImpl (index_bundle.js:29760)
at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (index_bundle.js:5980)
at Object.batchedUpdates (index_bundle.js:29682)
at Object.batchedUpdates (index_bundle.js:1824)
at dispatchEvent (index_bundle.js:29840)
```

The image is rendered but the error is shown in console.

My component:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class TopNavigation extends React.Component {

    render() {
            return (
                    <div className="top-navigation-holder">
                          <ul className="navigation container">
                                <li><img src={'/static/icons/menu.svg'} className="svg-icons" /></li>
                          </ul>
                    </div>
            )
    }
}
```

How do I solve the error? Also what is the reason behind the error?

I am using react 15.6.1

Comment: Are You sure error from this component?

Comment: yes I am sure. It occurs only when I add the image link. I have also tested by removing all components and placed only the above html in the root render function and same result.

Comment: Could it be the curly braces around the path? It is not a variable.

Comment: no. i checked removing them. still same result.

Comment: Stuck here too. Weird.